# How can i do Laravel pagination for multiple table results?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

In Laravel, I have multiple table results from controller to view. I need to do pagination for this set of results. How can I do that?

I have these many results from different tables

`return View::make('view')->with('data_array', $data_array)->with('count', $count)->with('paginate', $paginate);`

`data_array` has array result from multiple tables.

```
$employee_detail = EmployeeDetail::Select('employee_id', 'unique_type_id', 'unique_number')->get()->toArray();
        $paginate = EmployeeDetail::paginate(5);        
        $count = EmployeeDetail::Select('employee_id', 'unique_type_id', 'unique_number')->count();

        $data_array = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($employee_detail as $employeeKey => $employeeValue) {
            $kiosk_id = $employeeValue['employee_id'];
            $data_array[$i]['kiosk_id'] = $kiosk_id;
            $package_id = $employeeValue['unique_type_id'];
            $unique_number = $employeeValue['unique_number'];
            $data_array[$i]['unique_number'] = $unique_number;
            $carrier_details = CarrierDetails::Select('package_name', 'carrier_type_id')->where('id', '=', $package_id)
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
            foreach ($carrier_details as $packageDetailskey => $packageDetailsvalue) {
                $package_name = $packageDetailsvalue['package_name'];
                $data_array[$i]['package_name'] = $package_name;
                $carrier_type = $packageDetailsvalue['carrier_type_id'];
                $carrier_details = CarrierType::Select('carrier_name')->where('id', '=', $carrier_type)->get();
                foreach ($carrier_details as $carrierDetailsKey => $carrierDetailsValue) {
                    $carrier_name = $carrierDetailsValue['carrier_name'];
                }
                $data_array[$i]['carrier_name'] = $carrier_name;
                $i ++;
            }
```

please give me the suggestions.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show how do you build an array, show the queries.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Added queries @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here:

1. [Create a paginator manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

This [tutorial](http://psampaz.github.io/custom-data-pagination-with-laravel-5/) should help you.

2. Rewrite your code to use Eloquent relationships and use `with()` or `load()`. In this case you'll be able to use `paginate()` method.

If I were you I'd choose the second one.

Comment: Can you please give an overview on how to do second option? . Thanks

Comment: There is not easy way. You should start from learning about [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) and create relationships between models first.